# merge columns in numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a NumPy matrix like this one (it could have several columns, this is just an example:

```
array([[nan, nan],
       [nan, nan],
       ['value 1', nan],
       [nan, nan],
       [nan, nan],
       [nan, 'value 2']], dtype=object)
```

I need to merge all columns in this matrix, replacing nan values with the corresponding non-nan value (if exists). Example output:

```
array([[nan],
       [nan],
       ['value 1'],
       [nan],
       [nan],
       ['value 2']], dtype=object)
```

Is there a way to achieve this with some built-in function in NumPy?

EDIT: if there is more than one non-nan in single row, I will take the first non-nan value.

Values could be string, float or int

Comment: What if there is more than one non-nan in single row?

Comment: Are the values strings or numbers?

Comment: I think you're being downvoted and close-voted because you did not show any effort to solve the problem yourself first. Show us the code you've written, what you've tried, and where you got stuck. Include any errors or how the output you get is not what you want.

Comment: We can only guess as to why people downvote or close.  They don't tend to hang around and read comments.  But, yes, a little more effort might have been enough - for example an attempt to reduce one row.  And maybe a bit of wrestling with a `nan` equality test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the rows where the first column is `nan`. This works because `nan!=nan`:

```
rows = arr[:,0] != arr[:,0]
```

Update the first element of each chosen row with the second element:

```
arr[rows,0] = arr[rows,1]
```

Select the first column:

```
arr[:,[0]]
```